# ConnectyCube Push Notification in Flutter for IOS

Tags: flutter, connectycube

I am using ConnectyCube push notification for my Flutter App (IOS). But I didn't receive any notification yet. Follow the same Instructions Documentation https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/how-to-create-apns-certificate